# Facebook API not return email.It only return name and id

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk, cakephp-1.3

When i am try to change the facebook app id of my site.it returning name and id but it not return other details(email,user_birthday).i added redirect url and i give yes to Client OAuth Login ,Web OAuth Login  in fb setting.

sample code in cake php 1.3

```
$this->set('fb_login_url',$this->facebook->getLoginUrl((array(
                    'redirect_uri' => Router::url(array(
                        'controller' => 'users',
                        'action' => 'register',
                        'admin' => false
                    ) , true),

                   'scope' => 'email,user_birthday'
                ))));
```

In controller

```
 $me = $this->facebook->api('/me');
```

while i print it return only name and id .if everthing is correct or i want to change in fb setting.

Comment: please use this  $me = $this->facebook->api('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email,gender,age_range,first_name,last_name,link,locale,picture,location');

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

Comment: Hi @sradha thanks for the comment now it return email but it not return first_name,user_birthday.

Comment: Yes i have tried it in this way to get the data ,but it works for me

Comment: i will try again .thanks for the comment @sradha